# Controlling Magenot sort collectio by attribute

Tags: php, magento

I am using the FishPig module to display WordPress on my Magento site. I have selected some associated blog posts from a CMS Page and they display as I need to.

However I am using the postion boxes but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

I have tried adding `->addAttributeToSort('position')` to the `getPostCollection()` but this causes the page to break.

Full code as it is now.

```
    <?php if (($posts = $this->getPostCollection()) !== false): ?>
    <?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>

        <div class="box-collateral box-description" style="padding:5px 20px;">
            <!--<?php if ($title = $this->getTitle()): ?>
                <h2 style="margin-bottom:15px;">Blog <span style="color: #68d088;">Posts</span></h2>

            <?php endif; ?>-->
            <div class="std">
                <ul>
                <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>

                    <li class="related-blogs">
                        <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>"><h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?></h2></a>
                        <div class="content">
                            <?php 
                                $pos = strpos($post['post_content'], ' ', 300);
                                echo substr($post['post_content'],0,$pos );
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <a style="color:#68d088; font-weight:bold;" href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>">Read More...</a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what is the error message? when the page "breaks" is anything displayed or nothing?

Comment: @AndyJones No nothing is displayed

Comment: Did you enable magento logging? There should be an exception in your logs.